# ionViewLoaded not being called

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm trying to use the [Page Life Cycle Events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/#lifecycle-events) as seen here. I'm trying to use `ionViewDidLoad` but it's not firing for me. I created a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/boPgaYoFxWwxdFPEVXzF?p=preview) to put my example in the most simple terms as possible. I have a log statment inside of `ionViewDidLoad`, but it's not being fired. If you look at `page1.ts` and `home.ts` in the `plunkr` you'll see the log statements.

The basic code of each file is:

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular/index';
import { Page1 } from 'page1.ts'
import { Component } from "@angular/core";


@Component({
  templateUrl:"home.html"
})
export class HomePage {

  greeting: string;

  constructor(private nav: NavController) {

    }

    ionViewDidLoad(){
      console.log('home.ts view initialized');
  }

    goToPage1() {
      this.nav.push(Page1);
    }


}
```

In my own code, i'm making a call to an API and its firing everytime so I need a life cycle hook so that i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that since your page is a tab, the lifecycle events don't work in the same way they work for regular pages. If you need to do something every time a tab is selected (like obtaining data from a server), then check [this part](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/tabs/Tab/) of Ionic docs:

> Sometimes you may want to call a method instead of navigating to a new
>   page. **You can use the (ionSelect) event to call a method on your class
>   when the tab is selected**. Below is an example of presenting a modal
>   from one of the tabs.

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab (ionSelect)="getData()"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

And

```
export class Tabs {
  constructor(...) {

  }

  public getData() {
    // Awesome code doing awesome things...
  }
}
```

So you can use the `(ionSelect)="yourMethod()"` to make the call to that API every time the tab is selected.

Answer (score 2):

I think to use the Ionic specific lifecycle events you need to use the NavComponent to go push the views.

I replaced the `ionViewDidLoad()` with `ngOnInit()` and the console command fired as expected.

http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/