# http.get() does not return an observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ionic4, angular-httpclient

***NOTE: The problem is definetly the ionViewDidLoad() not being executed cause the http.get does get an observable.***
I'm trying to get the observable when executing a request in order to get its **json** response later but I don't get an error, and nothing is displayed in the browser's console either. I don't know why it does not return anything.

I have tried many urls and checked many times the imports. 
[console.log not pasting the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJzxh.png)
home.page.ts

```
    import { ServicioService } from '../servicio.service';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    ...
    ionViewDidLoad(){
          const hola = this.servicio.goWiki(this.userInput).
          subscribe((response) => {
            console.log(response);
           });
        }
```

servicio.service.ts

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

    @Injectable()
    export class ServicioService {

        constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
            console.log('goin!');
        }

        goWiki(userInput): Observable<any>{
            return this.http.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/top/.json?limit=105sort=hot');
        }
```

app.module.ts

```
    import { ServicioService } from './servicio.service';
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

    imports: [HttpClientModule, BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, ComponentesModule],
      providers: [
        ServicioService,...
```

I just hope to get an observable to be able to read it and extract specific data from it.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproduction of your issue, preferably in stackblitz

Comment: Are you sure `ionViewDidLoad ()` is called ? Please check this post:   [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40339833/ionviewloaded-not-being-called/40340156](ionViewLoaded not being called)

Comment: Maybe you can add a print message in the "ionViewDidLoad ()" using console. log to check if this method is executed

Comment: http.get returns an observable: Observable<Response>, and not Observable<whateveryouneed>, check this page: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/http/http-with-observables/

Comment: @NicuVlad I put a console.log() but does not return anything so it isn't being executed

Comment: @ThierryFalvo it isn't being called, I found out that's the problem. I looked up that post and didn't find out the answer to my problem. The http.get does get an observable so I think I just might put that into the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Ionic 4, in Angular you no longer have the `ionViewDidLoad` lifecycle hook. Use the standard Angular `ngOnInit` hook instead.

See https://medium.com/@paulstelzer/ionic-4-and-the-lifecycle-hooks-4fe9eabb2864

> Lifecycles in Ionic 4
>
> [...]
>
> Except `ionViewDidLoad` (because it’s the same like `ngOnInit`) and the two nav guards all Lifecycle hooks from Ionic 3 are still available

Comment: Thank you, that's it! I didn't even thougth about it.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a get on this URL: '*https://www.json.org*'

There maybe a bunch of things that may be going wrong here. One of them could be CORS.

If your web app does not allow CORS (cross-origin request sharing), then you will not get response back from the call.The call is essentially blocked by the browser (check your browser). The first call if you look at the network log will be OPTIONS instead of a get. Essentially the website should be returning the Http operation Verbs that it would be allowed to call.

Try calling a local iis server app on your machine or any machine on the same domain as the web app, http.get will work.

Comment: The link was wrong, I changed it. It is not the **.get** either, I think, cause if I put the **ionViewDidLoad** in the constructor:
```constructor(
    navcntrlr: NavController,
    private alertcontroller: AlertController, 
    public servicio: ServicioService) { this.ionViewDidLoad();}```
I get the data: {kind: "Listing", data: {…}} that is what I need, I think. However, **ionViewDidLoad()** shouldn't be executed there, that's nosense, right?

Answer (score 1):

It’s seems like you component is missing the http in the constructor and you are trying to call the service in the wrong way.

You don’t need to put it inside a veritable in the method.

Answer (score 1):

```
**service.ts**
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

 constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

getFirst(): Observable<any> {

return this.http.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/top/.json?limit=105sort=hot').pipe(map(res => {
  return res;
}));
```

}